# UTF-16BE to UTF-8 using Boost.Locale yields garbage

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I am working with an API which returns UTF-16BE strings. I need to convert those to UTF-8 for displaying inside a UI (which in turn accepts char* buffers). To that end, I decided to employ `boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf()` and write a conversion routine:

```
// defined by the API
typedef uint16_t t_wchar_t;
typedef std::basic_string<t_wchar_t> t_wstring;

char* ToUtf8(const t_wstring &utf16)
{
    // print out the input buffer, using printfs instead of cout because I have to
    printf("t_wchar_t = %zu, wchar_t = %zu, char = %zu\n", 
            sizeof(t_wchar_t), sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(char));
    const t_wchar_t *inBuf = utf16.c_str();
    const size_t inSize = utf16.size();
    // buf2str is my debugging function for printing buffers as raw bytes
    printf("UTF16 size: %zu, buf: %s\n", inSize, 
            buf2str(inBuf, inSize).c_str());

    // make a copy of the input buffer, prepend a BE BOM 
    // (didn't work without it, does not work with it either)
    t_wchar_t *workBuf = new t_wchar_t[inSize + 1];
    workBuf[0] = 0xfeff;
    std::memcpy(workBuf + 1, inBuf, inSize * sizeof(t_wchar_t));
    printf("Workbuf: %s\n", buf2str(workBuf, inSize + 1).c_str());

    // perform conversion, print out the result buffer
    const string utf8Str = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(workBuf, 
            workBuf + inSize + 1);
    const size_t utf8Size = utf8Str.size();
    printf("UTF8 size: %zu, buf: %s\n", utf8Size, 
            buf2str(utf8Str.c_str(), utf8Size).c_str());

    // allocate a char buffer, copy the result there and return the pointer
    char *ret = new char[utf8Size + 1];
    std::memcpy(ret, utf8Str.c_str(), (utf8Size + 1)*sizeof(char));
    printf("Return buf[%zu]: <%s>\n", 
            buf2str(ret, utf8Size + 1).c_str());
    delete [] workBuf;
    return ret;
}
```

This however returns garbage when run on the API strings as well as some test data:

```
int main()
{
    // simulate the input, make an example UTF-16BE stream from raw bytes
    const unsigned char test[] ={ '\0', 'H', '\0', 'e', '\0', 'l', '\0', 'l', '\0', 'o', 
            '\0', ',', '\0', ' ', '\0', 'w', '\0', 'o', '\0', 'r', '\0', 'l', 
            '\0', 'd', '\0', '!' };
    // create a t_wstring from the 16bit code sequences directly
    const t_wstring testStr(reinterpret_cast<const t_wchar_t*>(test), 13);
    printf("test data: %s\n", buf2str(testStr.c_str(), testStr.size()).c_str());

    char* utf8 = ToUtf8(testStr);
      delete [] utf8;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is some output from the program for the "Hello, world!" string. As you can see, the UTF8 buffer after the convertion contains garbage.

> test data: [13/26] '' (0) 'H' (72) '' (0) 'e' (101) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'o' (111) '' (0) ',' (44)
>   '' (0) ' ' (32) '' (0) 'w' (119) '' (0) 'o' (111) '' (0) 'r' (114) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'd' (100) '' (0) '!' (33)
>   t_wchar_t = 2, wchar_t = 4, char = 1
>   UTF16 size: 13, buf: [13/26] '' (0) 'H' (72) '' (0) 'e' (101) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'o' (111)
>   '' (0) ',' (44) '' (0) ' ' (32) '' (0) 'w' (119) '' (0) 'o' (111) '' (0) 'r' (114) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'd' (100)
>   '' (0) '!' (33)
>   Workbuf: [13/26] '' (0) 'H' (72) '' (0) 'e' (101) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'o' (111) '' (0) ',' (44)
>   '' (0) ' ' (32) '' (0) 'w' (119) '' (0) 'o' (111) '' (0) 'r' (114) '' (0) 'l' (108) '' (0) 'd' (100) '' (0) '!' (33)
>   UTF8 size: 42, buf: [42/42] '' (228) '' (160) '' (128) '' (230) '' (148) '' (128) '' (230) '' (176) '' (128) '' (230)
>   '' (176) '' (128) '' (230) '' (188) '' (128) '' (226) '' (176) '' (128) '' (226) '' (128) '' (128) '' (231) '' (156)
>   '' (128) '' (230) '' (188) '' (128) '' (231) '' (136) '' (128) '' (230) '' (176) '' (128) '' (230) '' (144) '' (128)
>   '' (226) '' (132) '' (128) '' (226) '' (188) '' (179)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @TheUndeadFish's comment, I added endianness conversion on my working buffer before conversion and now it works as expected:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < inSize; ++i)
{
    workBuf[i] = be16toh(workBuf[i]);
}
```

Comment: That BOM needs to be the bytes [0xFE followed by 0xFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). However, on many popular platforms (Intel) native endianness is LE (which will reverse that)

Comment: Thanks, the BOM was indeed reversed. However, when declared as `0xFFFE`, it didn't help either (it was the first thing I tried). Apparently, Boost.Locale or ICU ignore the BOM and go with the native endianness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in your case `utf_to_utf` is processing the input as if it was little-endian UTF16.

Taking the first 4 bytes:

You meant 00 72 00 101 to encode U+0048 U+0064.

When interpreted under the opposite endianness that encodes U+4800 U+6400.

When that's converted to UTF-8 it results in the bytes e4 a0 80 e6 94 80.

Representing those as decimal gives 228 160 128 230 148 128, which are the first values of your "garbage".

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble of converting the data. I expected this could be the case since the endianness of the target architecture is LE, but I was hoping that the BOM would do the trick. I don't suppose you know how to force `utf_to_utf` to operate in BE mode?

Comment: @neuviemeporte: The Boost documentation doesn't say much here except that it uses ICU, and according to the [ICU documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings), it only deals with *native-endian* UTF-16 strings; it cannot deal with fixed little- or big-endian strings.  Also, FWIW, the BOM you're inserting is native-endian as well.

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose endianness conversion is relatively simple. Thanks!